# Security implications of deserializing arbitray objects from YAML with yamldotnet

Tags: c#, .net, security, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm currently evaluating this library from a security perspective. Since YAML can be used to serialize objects, I was wondering if the defaults provided by the parser are set such that deserialization of arbitrary objects is prevented.
Putting it differently:

What are the steps needed to allow for the creation of any type of object give a YAML string containing the definition of a specific type?
From what I could tell going through the documentation, this behaviour is not easily reproducible, since the deserializer expects a type of an object to populate with the given data.

As a second, related question: Are validation checks that are present during the creation of objects (e.g. "Age" property can not be larger than 130 and smaller than 0) or when using a getter/setter pattern being used when creating the object, or is it possible to create objects that have unexpected data inside them that way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think this is really a question you should take to the library author, not us, to get the kind of trustworthy answer you'd want for evaluating security concerns. Also, please mind that you should not ask multiple questions at once here.

Comment: @flyx will do thanks and noted.